# php echo statement inside $output

Tags: php, variables, output

I have the following php code:

```
$skizzar_masonry_item_width = $masonry_item_width;
$skizzar_masonry_item_padding = $masonry_item_padding;
$skizzar_double_width_size = $masonry_item_width*2 +$masonry_item_padding;

$output .= '<style>.skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double, .skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double img {width:'.$skizzar_double_width_size.'}</style>';

return $output;
```

For some reason though, the value of `$skizzar_double_width_size` is not being added into the $output - is there a way to echo a value in an output variable?

Comment: Did you initialize your `$output` variable with `$output = "";` before you appended stuff?

Comment: @Rizier123 shouldn't make a difference if error_reporting is off.

Comment: Are you sure `$skizzar_double_width_size` has a value?

Comment: `var_dump($skizzar_double_width_size)` will tell you if there's anything in that var. And given your previous question, you really should sit down and study php syntax a bit better. "echo a value in an output variable"?

Comment: Also is this code in a function or do you want just to output this?

Comment: @MarcB I did var_dump as you suggested and get int(485) which is the correct value

Comment: then do a view source on the page that contains this css. Most likely the value's there, but not working because you didn't include any units. `width:485` in css is illegal. it should be `width:485px` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rizier123 mentioned, ensure you initialise any string variables before trying to append to them.

`$var = '';
$var .= 'I appended';
$var .= ' a string!';`

I would also like to strongly discourage you from using inline styles as well as generating them with inline PHP. Things get very messy very quickly.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if the variable is instantiated, yes you will get an error if error_reporting is on. However `$output` would still contain the value assigned.

Comment: From the looks of the original question, it's hard to determine whether the other variables have been defined at all so it's hard to really say much more than this. I'll expand with some debugging information. Actually looks like I don't have the rep so I'll have to do it here.

If it's vanilla PHP he should check the value of variables that aren't being set correctly using either `var_dump()`, `print_r()` or `echo` and fire off `die()` to halt script execution.

It's the only other explanation I can think of, either that or the code posted is in a function that isn't even called.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this you need to check that all the variables you are using in the calculation are valid before you panic.

So try

```
echo 'before I use these values they contain<br>';
echo '$masonry_item_width = ' . $masonry_item_width . '<br>';
echo '$masonry_item_padding = ' . $masonry_item_padding . '<br>';


$skizzar_masonry_item_width = $masonry_item_width;
$skizzar_masonry_item_padding = $masonry_item_padding;
$skizzar_double_width_size = $masonry_item_width*2 +$masonry_item_padding;

echo 'after moving the fields to an unnecessary intemediary field<br>';
echo '$skizzar_masonry_item_width = ' . $skizzar_masonry_item_width . '<br>';
echo '$skizzar_masonry_item_padding = ' . $skizzar_masonry_item_padding . '<br>';
echo '$skizzar_double_width_size = ' . $skizzar_double_width_size . '<br>';


$output .= '<style>.skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double, .skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double img {width:'.$skizzar_double_width_size.'}</style>';

echo $output;
```

This should identify which fields are causing you problems.

Also while testing always run with `display_errors = On` It saves so much time in the long run.